# fish evolution coding problem, approach to optimize it

Tags: java, arrays

Namita has magical fishes. Her fishes has the capability to evolve to become bigger fish. So, if the smaller fish touches a bigger or equivalent fish, then the bigger or equivalent fish disappears into water and the smaller fish evolves to become as large as the larger fish. Therefore, to avoid stray evolutions, she has kept her fishes in separate cells, arranged in a linear order. Now, she wants to evolve only one fish and she wants to choose the fish which will evolve maximum number of times. She wants your help in this. To make it more interesting, she has added signs of evolution with the fish cells. A cell assigned with +1 can only evolve with fishes on its right side and a cell assigned with -1 can only evolve with fishes on its left side. Can you complete this challenge?
Remember that the fishes are mindlessly evolving. This means that they evolve with the first big fish that comes in their way. Consider the following case. Here, Fish with size 5 can evolve in right direction.
5 12 10 11 13
Fish with size 5 will evolve 2 times like 5 -> 12 -> 13 and not 3 times like 5->10->11->13.
Note: If there is more than one fish which can evolve the maximum number of times, select the one with the greater size.
Input Format:
First line of input contains an integer t, representing the number of test cases.
For each test case, the first line contains an integer n, representing the number of fishes.
Second line of each case contains n space separated integers, representing the size of fishes.
Third line of each test case contains n space separated integers, being +1 or -1, representing the signs of evolution.

Output:
For each test case, you have to print the size of fish which will evolve maximum number of times, along with the direction it is going to evolve in. (Left for -1 and Right for +1)

I am finding the rightEvolution by traversing from right to left and then leftEvolution by going from left to right. and then finding the maximum of them. But I am getting TLE and wrong answer for test cases;

```
import java.util.*;

public  class Solution{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

        int t= sc.nextInt();
        while(t-->0)
        {
        int n =sc.nextInt();
        int [] sizes =new int[n];
        int [] direction= new int[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         sizes[i] = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
          direction[i]  =sc.nextInt();

       int [] rightEvolution = new int[n];
          //max evolution that every fish can achive while moving to right direction ,
          //   so we have to now from right to left
           rightEvolution[n-1]=0;
          for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
          {
             int j=i+1;
             int s=sizes[i];
              while( j<=n-1 && s>=sizes[j] )
                       j++;
                if(j<=n-1)
              rightEvolution[i] =rightEvolution[j]+1;
                else
                rightEvolution[i]=0;
          }

        int [] leftEvolution =new int[n];
            leftEvolution[0] =0;
         for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
         {
            int j=i-1;
             int s=sizes[i];
              while(j>=0 && s>=sizes[j])
                   j--;
              if(j>=0)
              leftEvolution[i]=leftEvolution[j]+1;
              else 
               leftEvolution[i]=0;
         }
        //  System.out.println("Right Evolution");
        //  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        //    System.out.print(rightEvolution[i]+" ");
          
        //   System.out.println();
        //    System.out.println("left evolution");
        //   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        //   System.out.print(leftEvolution[i]+" ");

         //find the maximum right evolution 
        int  maxr=0;
        int initSizeR=0;
         for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
             if(direction[i]==1)
              {
                 if(rightEvolution[i]>maxr)
                  {
                    maxr=rightEvolution[i];
                    initSizeR=sizes[i];
                  }
                 else if(rightEvolution[i]==maxr &&initSizeR<sizes[i])
                  {
                       initSizeR=sizes[i];
                  }
              }
           }

           //find the maximum size in left evolution
          int maxl=0;
          int initSizeL=0;
           for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
             if(direction[i]==-1)
             {
             if(leftEvolution[i]>maxl)
             {
               maxl=leftEvolution[i];
               initSizeL=sizes[i];

             }
           else  if(leftEvolution[i]==maxl && initSizeL<sizes[i])
              {
                initSizeL=sizes[i];
              }
             }
           }


           // find the maximum evolution out of  maximum left and right evolution and print the result
                if(maxr>maxl)
                {
                        System.out.println(initSizeR+" Right");
                }
                else if (maxr<maxl)
                {
                        System.out.println(initSizeL+" Left");
                }
                else if(maxr==maxl)
                {
                       if(initSizeL<initSizeR)
                          System.out.println(initSizeR+" Right");
                       else
                           System.out.println(initSizeL+" Left");
                }
             


        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't spam tags; your code is Java, so don't tag it C, C++, or Python. Explain in more detail how the code doesn't do what you expect. What inputs get what outputs, and what did you expect instead? See [ask].

Comment: This really needs more technical explanation than "getting wrong answer".

Comment: Do your own homework chief

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual [coding] challenge?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to augment the list of sizes, and evolution directions, while testing the fish.

Consider the following.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("enter number of test cases:  ");
int t = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println();
int n;
List<Integer> sizes, evolutions;
int fish;
StringBuilder string;
do {
    System.out.print("enter number of fish:  ");
    n = scanner.nextInt();
    sizes = new ArrayList<>(n);
    System.out.print("enter fish sizes:  ");
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)
        sizes.add(scanner.nextInt());
    evolutions = new ArrayList<>(n);
    System.out.print("enter evolution directions:  ");
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)
        evolutions.add(scanner.nextInt());
    string = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        if (evolutions.get(index) == -1) {
            if (index == 0) continue;
            if (sizes.get(index - 1) >= sizes.get(index)) {
                fish = sizes.get(index);
                sizes.set(index, sizes.get(index - 1));
                sizes.remove(index - 1);
                evolutions.remove(index-- - 1);
                n = sizes.size();
                if (index == 0) continue;
                if (sizes.get(index - 1) >= sizes.get(index)) {
                    sizes.set(index, sizes.get(index - 1));
                    sizes.remove(index - 1);
                    evolutions.remove(index-- - 1);
                    string.append("fish %d, maximum evolution leftward%n".formatted(fish));
                }
            }
        } else if (evolutions.get(index) == 1) {
            if (index == n - 1) continue;
            if (sizes.get(index + 1) >= sizes.get(index)) {
                fish = sizes.get(index);
                sizes.set(index, sizes.get(index + 1));
                sizes.remove(index + 1);
                evolutions.remove(index + 1);
                n = sizes.size();
                if (index == n - 1) continue;
                if (sizes.get(index + 1) >= sizes.get(index)) {
                    sizes.set(index, sizes.get(index + 1));
                    sizes.remove(index + 1);
                    evolutions.remove(index + 1);
                    string.append("fish %d, maximum evolution rightward%n".formatted(fish));
                }
            }
        }
        n = sizes.size();
    }
    System.out.println(string);
} while (--t > 0);
```

Within the *for-loop*, first check whether the fish will evolve in the left, or right direction.

```java
if (evolutions.get(index) == -1) {

} else if (evolutions.get(index) == 1) {

}
```

If it can, augment its size, and remove the corresponding indice.
Subsequently, adjusting *n* to preserve the *for-loop* conditional.

```java
sizes.set(index, sizes.get(index - 1));
sizes.remove(index - 1);
evolutions.remove(index-- - 1);
n = sizes.size();
```

And, since the fish can evolve a maximum of two times, check once more.
With, which in this case, needs to be recorded with it's direction.

```java
string.append("fish %d, maximum evolution leftward%n".formatted(fish));
```

Here is an example input and output.

```
enter number of test cases:  2

enter number of fish:  5
enter fish sizes:  5 12 10 11 13
enter evolution directions:  1 -1 1 1 -1
fish 10, maximum evolution rightward

enter number of fish:  10
enter fish sizes:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
enter evolution directions:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
fish 0, maximum evolution rightward
fish 3, maximum evolution rightward
fish 6, maximum evolution rightward
```

Fish 5 evolves once, to 12.
Fish 10 evolves twice, once to 11, and then to 13.

Fish 0 evolves twice, once to 1, and again to 2.
Fish 3 evolves twice, once to 4, and again to 5.
Fish 6 evolves twice, once to 7, and again to 8.
Fish 9 does not evolve.